# Firefox isn't showing Hindi language on web pages

Tags: linux, firefox, browser, unicode

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=hindi+language

Firefox is unable to show the Hindi and Japanese fonts inside any web pages and possibly some other unicode characters are proabably not looking good.
This is Firefox 78.6.0esr on Debian 10.7 CD version (December 2020 CD). Older version suffered the same. I have installed Hindi fonts from Firefox marketplace or whatever but it's not working.
What's the solution?

Image in included.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my own question. I needed to install "fonts-indic" package for my Debian distribution and the problem was solved. For Japanese languages, there must be another package.